# Blue/black borders around textures: OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl

[image: Tiles are pulled from tilesheet]

I have had this bug for awhile now. I can't seem to get rid of it. I am thinking I may just have to draw my quads as normal rectangles; and create the illusion they are "rotated" when they aren't (using the textures).

Anyway, as you can see from the image, there are blue borders around all my tiles. I can't seem to get them to go away. I have tried other tilesheets and the same problem appears - except sometimes it's a black border.

I will post a decent bit of code - just so you have all the resources necessary to understand what I am doing.

My OpenGL setup code:

```
//******** SET UP OPENGL *******
public void setUpOpenGL() {
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);               
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);      
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    // enable alpha blending
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

Drawing code:

```
@Override
public void drawTile(int tileX,  int tileY, Texture atlas) {

    int tileXcoord, tileYcoord;

    tileXcoord = (tileX - tileY) * (TILE_XHALF); // TILE_WIDTH = 128
    tileYcoord = (tileX + tileY) * (TILE_YHALF); // TILE_HEIGHT = 64

    atlas.bind();       

    GL11.glColor3f(255, 255, 255);  

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {
        setTextureCoordinates(1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(tileXcoord, tileYcoord);
        setTextureCoordinates(2);
        GL11.glVertex2f(tileXcoord + TILE_XHALF, tileYcoord + TILE_YHALF);
        setTextureCoordinates(3);
        GL11.glVertex2f(tileXcoord + (TILE_XHALF * 2), tileYcoord);
        setTextureCoordinates(4);
        GL11.glVertex2f(tileXcoord + TILE_XHALF, tileYcoord - TILE_YHALF);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();

}

//***** SET TEXTURE COORDINATES *****
public void setTextureCoordinates(int pos) {
        Rectangle rect = textureAtlas.getTexture(ID);

        float x = rect.getX(), y = rect.getY();
        float height = rect.getHeight(), width = rect.getWidth();

        switch (pos) {
        case 1 :
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(x, y + (height / 2)); 
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.03125f);
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
            break;

        case 2:
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(x + (width / 2), y + height);
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.03125f, 0.0625f);
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1f);
            break;

        case 3:
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(x + width, y + (height / 2));
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0625f, 0.03125f);
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0.5f);
            break;

        case 4:
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(x + (width / 2), y);
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.03125f, 0.0f);
            //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.0f);
            break;
        }

}
```

Where drawing code gets its coordinates from (gridW = 9, gridH = 9, tilePixelWidth = 128, tilePixelHeight = 64, tilePercentOfWidth/Height comes out too 0.0625; total image resolution = 2048 x 1024):

```
//**** GET ID SPECIFIC TEXTURE CELL ******
public Rectangle getTexture(int id) {

    int columnNumber = (int)(id % gridW); // Column of texture (using MOD so    I can get textures beyond next column [next row])
    int rowNumber = (int)(id / gridH); // Row number for texture            
    // TODO: Get texture selection working!
    // Create bounding box
    float tilePercentOfWidth = this.tilePixelWidth / this.tPWidth;
    float tilePercentOfHeight = this.tilePixelHeight / this.tPHeight;

    float boxX = (columnNumber * (tilePixelWidth / tPWidth));
    float boxY = (rowNumber * (tilePixelHeight / tPHeight));
    float boxWidth = tilePercentOfWidth;
    float boxHeight = tilePercentOfHeight;      
    // End bounding box creation

    Rectangle textureBounds = new Rectangle (boxX, boxY, boxWidth,     boxHeight);

    return textureBounds;
}
```

Comment: Either you texture sampling is off, which should be fixed by setting a wrapping mode, or your mesh contains holes, which can be checked by rendering it in a different color than the background.

Comment: I don't know a lot about texture mapping, but I do know that `GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);` is usually used immediately after you `bind()` a texture(but before drawing with it) to prevent blurriness. I don't think putting it in the initialization will help much. Perhaps the blue border is a result of the blurry pixels from the blue corner of your texture being blurred around the edges of each square?

Comment: It may very well help. The default filters are `GL_LINEAR` and `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` (bilinear). If you are using a tilemap and you have no border between tiles you cannot use linear filtering, or you get stuff like this.

Comment: @Brian_Entei: The filtering mode is a state of the texture object and setting it once for a texture suffices. No need to reset it after every bind. Modern OpenGL offers sampler objects, which allow to store this state independent from textures so that a consistent state can be used with multiple textures.

Comment: @datenwolf: The problem is it's never been set while any texture other than the default **0** is bound from the looks of this code.

Comment: @datenwolf Ah, okay. I do still have to set it after binding each of my textures(or else the textures are blurry), though I am using OpenGL 1.1.

Comment: @Brian_Entei: To set anything but the default you have to set it at least once after binding a texture. Also some OpenGL drivers are buggy and respect the setting only after one or sometimes the complete set of texture images has been set. But once set for a texture it's not necessary to reset it for this texture, except if you want a different filtering mode.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks for the explanation!